# Which way should I check exceptions in JNI?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

As we know, many methods in JNI may cause exception and cannot be called after exception caused that may crash the JVM. We can not only use ExceptionOccurred() or ExceptionCheck() to determine whether exception occurred or not, but also can simply check something not equal to NULL or 0. Which way is the best practice?

Comment: Would you like more infos?

Comment: @manuell Yes, more details are better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are only asking for "best practice", the answer is very straightforward:

1. **always** call `ExceptionCheck` or `ExceptionOccurred` when calling JNI functions which may raise exceptions.
2. **always** check return values from JNI functions

Calling `ExceptionOccurred` after each JNI call, preferably in a dedicated function, allows you to get some information on the exception, for logging, and also allows you to call `ExceptionClear`.

Make the dedicated function return void, and use the return values from the JNI functions to distinguish between normal and error paths.

Comment: Yes, it's better. I will try to update my answer later. If you want to do only one thing, use ExceptionOccurred and clear the exception is there is one.